# What's an approach for avoiding duplicate data in BigQuery based on a subset of columns?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm generating CSV files that contain log data for an application. The columns in the CSV file are `timestamp, source_address, destination_url, request_type`. When I load the CSV file into BigQuery, it just appends the data in the CSV into the existing table in BigQuery. I'd like to avoid duplicate `source_address, destination_url, request_type` sets and simply track the latest timestamp for such a set.

One way I've thought of doing this is to `GROUP BY source_address, destination_url, request_type` and get the `MAX(timestamp)`, but that means I'd have to save that query into a new table that I can then subsequently query and then copy it back into the original table that I periodically load the CSV file(s) into.

Is there a better way(s) to do this? The duplicates would be OK, except for the fact that Google charges for how much data a query is done over.

**---- EDIT #1 ----**

I'm also completely open to ways of de-duplicating the CSV data prior to loading into BiqQuery, so if anyone has any cool ideas of how to use command line tools piped together to diff CSV files based on certain column indexes or something of the like I'd love to hear about them.

**---- EDIT #2 ----**

OK, so I've been tinkering a bit with the `sort` command, and I *think* I might be on to something but I'd like someone else's opinion to confirm. Is `sort -t, -k1,1 -r logfile.csv | sort -u -t, -k2,4` doing what I'm wanting? This approach still requires me to create a new table instead of appending each time I want to load new data but that's OK if there's no other option(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way you suggested is generally the best option. You'll likely need a `GROUP EACH BY` instead of a `GROUP BY` if you have a lot of data.